# Assembly - Combining and storing characters from string with XOR

Tags: assembly, masm, xor, irvine32

I'm working on a program which takes a person's name, loops through each character in the name, and combines each character using the XOR command. The program clears the AL register only, NOT the rest of the EAX register.The final XOR result is then stored in the AL register.

Code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
myName BYTE "Joe Smith",0
tempName BYTE SIZEOF myName DUP(0)
.code
main PROC
mov al,0
mov esi,0
mov ecx,SIZEOF myName
top:
    xor al, myName[esi]
    inc esi
loop top
call DumpRegs
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

When I run the program using the name "Joe Smith", this is the output I'm getting:

```
EAX=768D332B EBX=7EFDE000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00401005
ESI=0000000A EDI=00000000 EBP=0018FF94 ESP=0018FF8C
EIP-004033FA EFL=00000206 CF=0  SF=0 ZF=0 OF=0 AF=0 PF=1
```

And I should be getting this:

```
EAX=0000002B EBX=7EFDE000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00405000
ESI=00405009 EDI=00000000 EBP=0018FF94 ESP=0018FF8C
EIP=00401045 EFL=00000206 CF=0 SF=0 ZF=0 OF=0 AF=0 PF=1
```

I'm having a few other problems with this as well. First, I'm not sure how "Joe Smith" translates to 0000002B in hexadecimal. Also I'm just not sure if I'm storing the XOR result correctly in the AL register in order for it to come up with the right output. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You said yourself that you only clear `AL` and not `EAX`, so why do you expect the top 24 bits to be zero? If you want that, clear all of `EAX` at the start. `2B` is the correct result, it's the XOR of the ascii code of the characters.

Comment: Windows calculator, in programmers mode, comes with XOR operation. It can also change base to binary. Use it to check your results.

Comment: I expect that because that is the correct output given in one of the examples.

Comment: Which part is confusing? If you want the top bits to be clear, clear them yourself. If you don't clear them, and even say so, then you won't get zeroes there. You can "expect" all you want, but the processor is only doing what you tell it to. So replace the `mov al, 0` with `mov eax, 0` or `xor eax, eax` and be done with it.

Comment: Please explain why you expect `ESI=00405009`, and not `ESI=0000000A`? It should be `ESI=00000009` but you included the terminating zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP asked *I'm not sure how "Joe Smith" translates to `0000002B` in hexadecimal.*

```
char    ASCII   binary      hex
-----   -----   ---------   ---
J        74     0100 1010   4A
o       111     0110 1111   6F
e       101     0110 0101   65
(space)  32     0010 0000   20
S        83     0101 0011   53
m       109     0110 1101   6D
i       105     0110 1001   69
t       116     0111 0100   74
h       104     0110 1000   68
(zero)    0     0000 0000   00      (this was included but has no effect on XOR)
        -----   ---------   ---
XOR  =   43     0010 1011   2B
```

In each column of the binary bit values, an odd number of `1` bits will result in a `1`, an even number of `1` bits will result in a `0`.